# Weird behavior of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I have weird problem with ListView on android 2.3. Application is simple todo list with EditText and ListView. Each time you write text and press ENTER text is added to ListView. Problem happend when I add 3rd element, order in ListView mess up (3rd element become 1st). I solve this problem so I rebind data every time in getView but on that way I lose ViewHolder pattern optimization. On 4.0 I don't have problem with same code :). Does anyone know what is reason for this behaviour?

This is my getView method.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder view;
    if(convertView == null) {

        convertView = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.todo_single_row, parent, false);

        view = new ViewHolder();
        view.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvToDoText);
        view.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvToDoDate);

        convertView.setTag(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    view.text.setText(ToDoList.getInstance().getToDoList().get(position).getText());
    view.date.setText(ToDoList.getInstance().getToDoList().get(position).getDate().toString());

    return convertView;
}
```

I try also to sort my adapter but did not help :(.

```
Comparator<Item> comparator = new Comparator<Item>() {
         public int compare(final Item item1, final Item item2) {
                return item1.getText().compareToIgnoreCase(item2.getText());
              };
    };

public class Item {
private String text;
private Date date;

public Item(String text) {

    this.text = text;
    this.date = new Date(java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually happens because usually `getView()` processes rows in an order that Android determines. Many people think this is called sequentially and it's not, it's called within an order that establishes the `Adapter`.

You can, however, override this behavior. In that case, you could simply declare a `Comparator`. For instance, if the content of your rows are strings, this would be one way:

```
Comparator alphabeticalOrder = new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(final String str1, final String str2) {
    return str1.compareToIgnoreCase(str2);
  };
};
```

Afterwards, you simply set it on your `Adapter`.

```
adapter.sort(alphabeticalOrder);
```

Comment: Sorting will basically add an upper layout to the rendering operation of your rows. It will know it has to render, but also counts on that you've defined a `.sort()` method and this will survive, so your `ListView` will be sorted.

Comment: Yep, you have to call `.sort()` each time you add something. I use this, for example: `elemlist.add(nick2ban);` `adapter.sort(alphabet);` `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Please update your question and add your `Comparator`, and in case you're using a compound class, include it also.

Comment: Ok, after seeing your update, replace `return item1.getText().compareToIgnoreCase(item2.getText());` by `return item1.text.getText().compareToIgnoreCase(item2.text.getText());` I know they are private, use a `getMyText()` method or something like that or set them `public`, but currently you're getting the `String` representation of your Item, not the text inside!

Comment: Should indeed, and does?

Answer (score 1):

On 2.3 and earlier versions of Android list view elements are indexed by what is visible. You need to use listView.getFirstVisible() to get a specific element.